# Date field from MS SQL Server indexed as different date in Apache Solr

Tags: sql-server, date, solr, sql-server-2012, utc

A weird thing happens where the date stored in MSSQL Server is indexed as a different value in Solr:

Value in MSSQL Server in the 'createdate' column: `2016-10-12 00:00:00.000`
But when indexed in Solr the value becomes: `2016-10-11T22:00:00Z`

Schema.xml definitions:

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="createdate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

The server time setting is: UTC+1 and the SQL Server `createdate` column type is of `datetime`.

Why is it indexed in Solr as a different value and how can I fix it?

I'm using Solr 4.3.1 and SQL Server 2012 Express

**update 1**

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb" user="myuser" password="mypwd" />
    <document name="reviews">
        <entity pk="compoundid" name="review" query="SELECT ('1_' + CAST(id as nvarchar(10)))as compoundid, r.id, title AS reviewtitle,reviewtext,overall_score AS overallscore,r.createdate 
FROM reviews r">
```

Also, the defaultvalue setting in SQL Server of createdate is set to `(((1)/(1))/(1900))`

Comment: What are the timezone/location settings of the server(s) in question here? What is the data type of your SQL Server `createdate` column?

Comment: Ah, I forgot. Updated the post.

Comment: How do you get the information _out_ of the SQL Server? I think it might be messing up timezones at that point.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch see my update 1...thanks!